# Set "editor" role to existing user

Tags: wp-query, users, user-roles

Using the User ID of an existing user, how do I change the role to Editor?

Here's what I tried:

```
$wpdb->query("UPDATE wp_usermeta SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:6:\"editor\";b:1;}' WHERE user_id = '$user_id' AND meta_key = 'wp_capabilities'");
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usermeta key that stores the user's role has a prefix in the name, the one set in the `wp-config.php` file. So `meta_key` will have the form `{prefix}_capabilities` and your query should look like

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
        $wpdb->prepare(
          "UPDATE {$wpdb->usermeta} SET meta_value = 'a:1:{s:6:\"editor\";b:1;}' WHERE user_id = %d AND meta_key = '{$wpdb->prefix}capabilities'",
          $user_id ) 
);
```

You do not need to write SQL query. You can achieve the same by fetching the `WP_User` object with [`get_userdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata) function and set new role with the method [set_role](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_User#set_role.28.24role.29) (or `remove_role` and `add_role` to change only one of the roles).

```
$my_user_id = 12345;   // user ID for changing role
$my_user = get_userdata($my_user_id);
if ( $my_user instanceof WP_User )
    $my_user->set_role('editor');
```

Comment: Thank you! The second solution worked perfectly